# look for consecutive values and give points accordingly

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table here : table1

```
employee ID     Reporting Manager       EmployeeName    Week No.        Points
1                  Mr. A                    Bob         week1            -10
2                  Mr. A                    Deepak      week1             50
3                  Mr. B                    Brinda      week1             60
4                  Mr. B                    Chriss      week1            -10
1                  Mr. A                    Bob         week2            -10
2                  Mr. A                    Deepak      week2             40
3                  Mr. B                    Brinda      week2             20
4                  Mr. B                    Chriss      week2             90
1                  Mr. A                    Bob         week3             -10
2                  Mr. A                    Deepak      week3             30
3                  Mr. B                    Brinda      week3             40
4                  Mr. B                    Chriss      week3             50
1                  Mr. A                    Bob         week4            -10
2                  Mr. A                    Deepak      week4            -10
3                  Mr. B                    Brinda      week4            -10
4                  Mr. B                    Chriss      week4             30
1                  Mr. A                    Bob         week5            -10
2                  Mr. A                    Deepak      week5            -10
3                  Mr. B                    Brinda      week5             20
4                  Mr. B                    Chriss      week5             50
```

In the "week No"column ,
I have data for 5 consecutive weeks,every week I want to check these conditions-

1.Every week I will check the current week's points.If the points value is -10 for the current week and the previous week's points is also -10 then -40 is added  in table 2(below table) in totalpoints field of that particular Employee.(plz see EmployeeName column)

2.Again we check it for current week and prevoius two week's points.If the score is -10 for three weeks consecutively the reward -100 for that person and added to total points field in table 2.(below table)

3.
Similarly for consecutive four weeks i.e current week and the previous 3 week's if points is -10 ,then add -200 to table2's total points field.

```
employee ID     Employee Name    Total points
1                  Bob             -50
2                  Deepak          110
3                  Brinda          130
4                  Chriss          210
```

**Possible solution (faulty) :**

```
; WITH 
n as (
    select [EmployeeName], CAST(SUBSTRING([Week No.],5,10) AS INT) as wk, Points as pt  
    from YourTable --> Change this to your table
),
sc as (
    select w.*, case w.pt when -10 then (case w1.pt when -10 then (case w2.pt when -10 then (case w3.pt when -10 then -200 else -100 end) else -40 end) else 0 end) else 0 end x
    from n w
    left join n w1 on w.[EmployeeName] = w1.[EmployeeName] and w.wk = w1.wk+1
    left join n w2 on w.[EmployeeName] = w2.[EmployeeName] and w.wk = w2.wk+2
    left join n w3 on w.[EmployeeName] = w3.[EmployeeName] and w.wk = w3.wk+3
),
l as (
    select *, pt+x as total
    from sc
),
s as (
    select [EmployeeName], sum(total) total
    from l
    group by [EmployeeName]
)
select *
from s
```

Can anyone help me on how to achieve this? I'm using sql server 2012.

Comment: You need check [**LEAD and LAG**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the input.let me see. @JuanCarlosOropeza

Comment: case 3. shouldnt be -150 instead of -200? -50 for each -10 after first one?

Comment: The points are rewarded for each individual case.Its not related.Whichever case satisfies,its relevant query will be run and points will be rewarded accordingly. That is why , the points rewarded can be -200 or -150 or or -500.My point is that value shouldnot matter .Thanks. @JuanCarlosOropeza

Comment: can you put in your output what values are add it like a comment? like `-- -10 -10 -50 -10 ` and explain why.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: @teja Output is there, the logic not so much.

Comment: check this demo. Not sure if is what you want but will help you to start. http://rextester.com/MXGNY10742

Comment: That value ,which is being subtracted (i.e points rewarded) is a penalty that I want to add to the value of Totalpoints in Table2 .I just want to check if -10 occurs for  an employee consecutively for 2, 3 or 4 times and penaltize some points.

Comment: @Teja the desired output is to add the rewarded points to "totalpoints" column in table 2

Comment: but how bob get only -50? have 5x(-10) with -200 penalty should be at least -250.

Comment: I just checked all the employees and only Deepak seems to be having a different value for total points and the rest of them have correct totalpoints value as per input data....

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I understand your concern.Plz dont pay any heed to the points at "Totalpoints " column of table2.I have run many other queries and come to that value.We just need to add the penalty points to whatever value we have at that column.

Comment: So you only want the penalty?

Comment: Sorry, but your question isnt clear enough. That logic can be interpreted in many ways. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/GHQW83226)**

```
WITH cte as (
    SELECT *, 
           LAG([Points], 1) OVER (PARTITION BY [employee ID] ORDER BY [Week No]) as prev1_points,
           LAG([Points], 2) OVER (PARTITION BY [employee ID] ORDER BY [Week No]) as prev2_points,
           LAG([Points], 3) OVER (PARTITION BY [employee ID] ORDER BY [Week No]) as prev3_points
    FROM employee
)
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN [Points] = -10 AND prev1_points = -10  AND prev2_points = -10  AND prev3_points = -10 
            THEN -200
            WHEN [Points] = -10 AND prev1_points = -10  AND prev2_points = -10 
            THEN -100
            WHEN [Points] = -10 AND prev1_points = -10
            THEN -50
            ELSE 0
       END penalty       
FROM cte
```

**FINAL OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Thanks but we are not looking at the total number of -10.We need to check if -10s appear consecutively.If -10 appears twice consecutively ,thrice consecutively or four times consecutively.

Comment: what if appear `[-10,-10,40,-10,-10]` ? two consecutive twice

Comment: your code checks for two consecutive weeks.This way we need it for three or four consecutive weeks whichever applicable for that employee.and then add those points to table2

Comment: Yes, was my mistake try to guess why you want. Please put more effort in explain your problem next time.

Comment: [-10,-10,40,-10,-10] lets say this value is for week 1 to week5, then on week2 penalty of -50 is added to table 2,again on week3 no penalty as its not consecutively -10 for two or three or four weeks.Same happens on week4 as not consecutively -10.Last on week5 -50 again penalty.

Comment: then for `[-10,-10,-10,-10,-10]` the penaltys are `[0,-50,-100,-150,-200]` ? for -500 penalty?

Comment: my bad ,will take care next time to explain as clearly as possible.you can directly copy the above table rather than creating a table.Thanks for the effort,anyway

Comment: [-10,-10,-10,-10,-10] - on first week no penalty, week2 penalty of -50 ,week 3 penalty of -100,week 4 penalty of -200.also week 5 ,penalty of -200.When we are on a particular week,we need to check the prevoius week and current week,previous two weeks and current week.previous three weeks and current week.We are not going beyond that.At the max we will check the current week and three previous weeks.That is why,when on week5 we  will know that the current week and previous three week's value is -10.So for week5 the value is -200 only.

Comment: looks perfect.Thanks a ton.you a genius.

Comment: I have a question.I have created a view here with your code and add the value from the penalty column to the total of another table "EmployeeTable". I tried putting everything within a stored procedure.Now after creating a view I want to update the view everytime the stored procedure  runs next time.How can that be made possible ? Thanks  .....Link :http://rextester.com/FSN8036

Comment: you should create a new question and give a more detailed description of your requirement. Right now not sure what you need.